# IIS SignalR Websocket Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 (no reason given)

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net

My project runs smoothly locally but when I run it on IIS, I get the error in the picture.

Note: Front end React Back end .Net core web api 6.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODhF7.png)

To activate websocket, I added the websocket protocol from the adding roles and features section and activated websocket in the relevant project.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6wjW.png)

Comment: Can you post your signalr code?

Comment: Looks similar to following : https://forum.arduino.cc/t/error-1006-abnormal-close-websocket/1023950/6